# Consolidating large table

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

I need some help with a complex query. Table def:

```
                                        Table "public.agent_log"
     Column      |           Type           |                          Modifiers                         
-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 class           | text                     |
 hostname        | text                     |
 ip_address      | text                     |
 promise_handle  | text                     |
 promiser        | text                     |
 promisee        | text                     |
 policy_server   | text                     |
 rowId           | integer                  | not null default nextval('"agent_log_rowId_seq"'::regclass)
 timestamp       | timestamp with time zone |
 promise_outcome | text                     |
Indexes:
    "primary_key" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("rowId")
    "client_by_timestamp" btree ("timestamp", class)
```

Each line in the table is a log. There will be many rows that are the same except for the timestamp. As the data ages, I want to cull the rows. I want to group records that have the same combination of class, ip_address, and hostname, and keep the highest timestamp for each day from each group. Example:

```
2014-01-22T13:44:00 any 192.168.0.1 moon.example.com ...
2014-01-22T14:44:00 any 192.168.0.1 moon.example.com ... KEEP
2014-01-22T14:44:00 any 192.168.0.2 mars.example.com ... KEEP
2014-01-22T13:44:00 any 192.168.0.2 mars.example.com ...
2014-01-23T13:44:00 any 192.168.0.1 moon.example.com ...
2014-01-23T14:44:00 any 192.168.0.1 moon.example.com ... KEEP
2014-01-23T14:44:00 any 192.168.0.2 mars.example.com ... KEEP
2014-01-23T13:44:00 any 192.168.0.2 mars.example.com ...
2014-01-22T13:44:00 cpu_1 192.168.0.1 moon.example.com ...
2014-01-22T14:44:00 cpu_1 192.168.0.1 moon.example.com ... KEEP
2014-01-22T14:44:00 cpu_1 192.168.0.2 mars.example.com ... KEEP
2014-01-22T13:44:00 cpu_1 192.168.0.2 mars.example.com ...
2014-01-23T13:44:00 cpu_1 192.168.0.1 moon.example.com ...
2014-01-23T14:44:00 cpu_1 192.168.0.1 moon.example.com ... KEEP
2014-01-23T14:44:00 cpu_1 192.168.0.2 mars.example.com ... KEEP
2014-01-23T13:44:00 cpu_1 192.168.0.2 mars.example.com ...
```

I'm testing with this, note that I'm using select instead of delete for this test. I can't get the where correct and the few things I've tried resulted in a very long query. Any suggestions for improvement or alternate approaches welcome.

```
explain SELECT * FROM agent_log 
WHERE 
NOT IN (
   SELECT
          class,
          max(timestamp) as timestamp,
          hostname,
          ip_address,
          promise_handle,
          promiser,
          promisee,
          policy_server,
          promise_outcome
      FROM agent_log
      WHERE timestamp < now() - interval '7 days' 
      GROUP BY
          class,
          DATE_TRUNC( 'day', timestamp),
          hostname,
          ip_address,
          promise_handle,
          promiser,
          promisee,
          policy_server,
          promise_outcome
)
AND timestamp < now() - interval '7 days'
```

Comment: Which version of Postgres?

Comment: @ypercube version 8.4

Answer (score 1):

> I want to group records that have the same combination of `class`,
>   `ip_address`, and `hostname`, and keep the highest `timestamp` for each day
>   from each group.

Not using the column name `timestamp` (like you shouldn't either). It's a [reserved word in SQL and a basic type name in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Using `ts` instead.

The query is surprisingly simple with `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (class, ip_address, hostname, ts::date) *
FROM   agent_log
WHERE  ts < now() - interval '7 days'
ORDER  BY class, ip_address, hostname, ts::date, ts DESC;
```

Detailed explanation:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)